# Flutter issue: listview rebuilding items when scrolled

Tags: flutter

When i scroll to the bottom of my listview, the bottom item gets rebuilt. The same when i scroll to the top, my first item gets rebuilt. The first item is a card with selectable chips that get unselected when this happens. And the "entrance" animation replays as well. How can i stop this?

Here's the basic code (it uses the simple_animations package and I can't seem to reproduce the problem with the chips, but I still have problems with the animations):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _chips = ['Hello', 'World'];

  List _selected = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Issue demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          FadeIn(
            1,
            Card(
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 10,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  _chips.length,
                  (int index) => InputChip(
                      label: Text(_chips[index]),
                      selected: _selected.contains(_chips[index]),
                      onSelected: (selected) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (selected) {
                            _selected.add(_chips[index]);
                          } else {
                            _selected.remove(_chips[index]);
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FadeIn(1.5, Text('A', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(2, Text('Very', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(2.5, Text('Big', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(3, Text('Scroll', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(3.5, Text('View', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(4, Text('With', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(4.5, Text('Lots', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(5, Text('Of', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(5.5,Text('Items', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(
            6,
            Card(
              child: Text('Last item',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FadeIn extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeIn(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity")
          .add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateX").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 130.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (300 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(animation["translateX"], 0), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You should run this yourself to fully understand the issue

Comment: Can you post more details? Maybe a code example.

Comment: Just a sec, I'll post some code in a minute...

Comment: Hmm I now understand what you mean by rebuild. That is because when the listView items of off the screen, they get "discarded", and then rebuild again when the listView start to scroll in that direction again. In short, a list view only retains its visible children plus a buffer of a few more items. Maybe you can save the a state in order to animate only on the first time.

Answer (score 45):

To keep elements in ListView alive (not re-render when scrolling back), you should user parameter `addAutomaticKeepAlives: true` . And every element in ListView have to be StatefulWidget with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.

Here is the code that I has edited for you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List _chips = ['Hello', 'World'];

  List _selected = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Issue demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          FadeIn(
            1,
            Card(
              child: Wrap(
                spacing: 10,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  _chips.length,
                  (int index) => InputChip(
                      label: Text(_chips[index]),
                      selected: _selected.contains(_chips[index]),
                      onSelected: (selected) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (selected) {
                            _selected.add(_chips[index]);
                          } else {
                            _selected.remove(_chips[index]);
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FadeIn(1.5, Text('A', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(2, Text('Very', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(2.5, Text('Big', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(3, Text('Scroll', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(3.5, Text('View', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(4, Text('With', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(4.5, Text('Lots', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(5, Text('Of', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(5.5,Text('Items', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4)),
          FadeIn(
            6,
            Card(
              child: Text('Last item',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FadeIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;
  FadeIn(this.delay, this.child);
  _FadeInState createState() => _FadeInState();
}

class _FadeInState extends State<FadeIn> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);//this line is needed

    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity")
          .add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateX").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 130.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (300 * widget.delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: widget.child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(animation["translateX"], 0), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, I'm having the same problem but with a CustomScrollView instead of ListView...

I've tried this fix but it doesn't work... Would you be able to help?

Comment: The EasyWebView keeps rebuilding when scrolling.. I can't figure out a way to make it stop..

https://pastebin.com/bmQdiTFp

Comment: `super.build` must be called in `State.build` to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`. So, add this line before returning a widget: `super.build(context);`

Comment: For CustomScrollView use cacheExtent parameter with large value.