# Unwanted animation while scrolling down the ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, animation, scroll

I have listview.builder widget which have several ListView.builder and GridView.count with `scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal`   inside of it. All the data comes from the services and I am using FutureBuilder to fetch them. My problem is whenever I scroll the main ListView.builder,other listview items comes with animation(items comes from left, from right). Specially if I scroll fast. I didn't use any animation, and I don't have any idea about the problem, maybe its rebuilding everytime I scroll the lisview, but I am using  `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` for main ListView. Do you have any idea? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be duplicate, I solved my problem using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57984979/10025471

The problem is everytime I scroll the listview, it's children rebuilding again and again. So I convert to stateful widget all of the children and I added `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to all of them. Now, there is no unwanted animation, and redundant rebuild