# How to skip some Dates Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datepicker, widget

I try to display dates of weeks. but based on requirement i need to skip Saturday and Sunday every time.

[image: here is example of displaying date]

here is code of date list:-

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 7,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => dateWidget(index),
      ),
```

here is code of dateWidget() method which is used for displaying dates:-

```
Widget dateWidget(int i) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
        width: 10.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          color: AppColor.premiumBlue,
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              labels(text: DateFormat('EE').format(tempDate).toUpperCase()),
              labels(
                text: tempDate.day.toString(),
                color: AppColor.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I need to skip Saturday and Sunday dates. if i enter 7 so, display 7 dates and also skip Saturday and Sunday. If any date is cut then last date should also be added.

For example:-

I enter 7, means i want to display 7 date from today.
So, happen like this..
17-FRI, 18-SAT, 19-SUN, 20-MON, 21-TUE, 22-WED, 23-THU (currently happen this)

and want to skip Saturday and Sunday.
So, happen like this..
17-FRI, 20-MON, 21-TUE, 22-WED, 23-THU, 24-FRI (I want like this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty sizedBox based on weekday

```dart
  Widget dateWidget(int i) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));

    if (tempDate.weekday > 5) {
      //6 and 7 for sat&sunday
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
```

Comment: Hello, Yeasin...
Thanks for answering me. but i also need to add dates.

I enter 7, means i want to display 7 date from today. So, happen like this.. 17-FRI, 18-SAT, 19-SUN, 20-MON, 21-TUE, 22-WED, 23-THU (currently happen this)

and want to skip Saturday and Sunday. So, happen like this.. 17-FRI, 20-MON, 21-TUE, 22-WED, 23-THU, 24-FRI (I want like this.)

Comment: try increment itemCount  like `itemCount: 7+2,`

Comment: but how can i increase count, because i need only 7 dates, and also i can't increase count because tempDate is in dateWidget method. and once they call, I can't change that item count.

Comment: what do you get after chaning it

Comment: you mean after change itemCount ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh is saying that if you just change it to 9 days, then you will be displaying 7 days since it will not display the weekends.

Comment: Hello, raw-chicken...
I understood that, but i can't change item count after calling ListView.builder. That's why their suggestion didn't work for me.

Comment: hope raw-chicken post answer your question

Answer (score 0):

### New Solution

Instead of using `ListView.builder`, pass in a list of the generated widgets to a `ListView` as so:

```
...
child: ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: generateDateWidgets(24),
);
```

```
List<Widget> generateDateWidgets(int count) {
  int weekends = 0;
  return List.generate(
    count,
    (index) {
      DateTime tempDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index + weekends));
      if (tempDate.weekday > 5) {
        int offset = 7 - tempDate.weekday + 1;
        tempDate = tempDate.add(Duration(days: offset));
        weekends += offset;
      }
      return dateWidget(tempDate);
    },
  );
}
```

`dateWidget` remains unchanged

```
Widget dateWidget(DateTime date) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
      width: 10.0,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        color: AppColor.premiumBlue,
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            labels(text: DateFormat('EE').format(date).toUpperCase()),
            labels(
              text: date.day.toString(),
              color: AppColor.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

### Old Solution (doesn't work)

Note: this solution doesn't work since ListView.builder

One solution (that isn't that great, but works) is to do it like so by doing the calculations before creating the dateWidget:

```
var weekends = 0; //define a count variable somwhere above ListView.builder
...
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 7,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index + weekends));
    if (tempDate.weekday > 5) {
      int offset = 7 - tempDate.weekday + 1;
      tempDate = tempDate.add(Duration(days: offset));
      weekends += offset;
    }
    return dateWidget(tempDate);
  },
);
```

And then

```
Widget dateWidget(DateTime date) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
      width: 10.0,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        color: AppColor.premiumBlue,
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            labels(text: DateFormat('EE').format(date).toUpperCase()),
            labels(
              text: date.day.toString(),
              color: AppColor.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

An alternative solution would be to do what @YeasinSheikh suggested. Instead of using a number to determine the number of weekdays we want, set a certain date you want to have `dateWidgets` to and then calculate the number of days you need and put that into `itemCount`.

Comment: It's work but when I enter large itemCount like 24, The starting dates was changed. I mean they change value when I'm scrolling.

Comment: Apparently that is a thing I did not realize [existed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980225/flutter-issue-listview-rebuilding-items-when-scrolled), I've updated so that it should not change value while you scroll.